# How to escape all metacharacters at once

Tags: regex

Would like to escape all metacharacters from text

. [ ] { } ( ) \ ^ $ | ? * +

Want to automatically add \
To escape metacharacters

Comment: What do you mean by escaping all metacharacters at once? As in you want your regex expression to treat every character as its literal value?

Comment: Which programming language are you using, as different languages have different flavors of regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = "The quick brown foxed jumped over []"+
           " ^ & * ? \\ the funny characters";
test = test.replaceAll("([\\Q{}()[]^$|?*+&$\\E])",  "\\\\$1");

System.out.println(test);
```

This works as follows:

1. The first argument to replaceAll is a regex. It has a capture block between the outside parens `()`.
2. Inside the parens is `character class` `[]` which describes the characters I want to replace.  But since they are special, I need to quote them so they don't get interpreted by the regex engine. The `\Q` and `\E` quote everything between them. To get a single backslash to the regex engine I have to quote one with a backslash itself.
3. In the second argument, the `$1` is a back reference to what was captured in the matched character class.  To precede it with a single backslash I have to put in  four of them.  The java compiler reduces `\\\\` to `\\`.  And the regex engine reduces `\\` to just a `\` for replacement.

The regex and its back reference are fairly standard features of most regex engines.  It is possible that in some languages, the escaping of the backslashes to by pass the `language compiler/interpreter` and the `regex engine` may be processed differently.  And the `test.replaceAll` is `Java`.

Comment: This was answered two days ago.  Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Pattern` directly, then it is simplest to use `Pattern.quote` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)) to create a regex (or sub-regex) that matches a literal string irrespective of metacharacters.  For example:

```
String exact = "[ ] { } ( ) \\ ^ $ | ? * + &";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(exact));
```

The resulting pattern matches the `exact` string.

```
pat.matcher(exact).match(); // returns true
```

(Note that the escaping of `\` in the above is *only* necessary because `exact` is a Java string literal.)